# Update List Item After Delete Action in Flutter

Tags: flutter

Hello I am new to flutter and I have a problem  to update the list after executing a deleting an item from the database. Some said to use setState, but I still don't know how to implement it in my code. Tried to call seState right after the delete action, but still nothing happened. Still have some trouble to understand which component to update in Flutter. Thank you.

```
class ProfileView extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    // TODO: implement createState
    return _ProfileViewState();
  }
}

class _ProfileViewState extends State<ProfileView> {
  late Future<List<Patient>> _patients;
  late PatientService patientService;


  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    patientService = PatientService();
    _patients = patientService.getPatient();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Profile')),
        body: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
              Flexible(
                child: SizedBox(
                  child: FutureBuilder<List<Patient>>(
                    future: _patients,
                    builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
                      if(snapshot.hasError) {
                        print(snapshot);
                        return Center(
                          child: Text("Error"),
                        );
                      } else if (snapshot.hasData){
                          List<Patient> patients = snapshot.data;
                          return _buildListView(patients);
                      } else {
                        return Center(
                          child: Container(),
                        );
                      }
                    },
                  ),
                ),
              )
          ],
    ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildListView(List<Patient> patients) {

    return ListView.separated(
        separatorBuilder: (BuildContext context, int i) => Divider(color: Colors.grey[400]),
        itemCount: patients.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          Patient patient = patients[index];
          return Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              Flexible(
                  child: SizedBox(
                    child: ListTile(
                      title: Text(patient.firstName),
                      subtitle: Text(patient.phone),
                      trailing: IconButton(
                        icon: new Icon(const IconData(0xf4c4, fontFamily: 'Roboto'), size: 48.0, color: Colors.red), 
                        onPressed: () {
                          patientService.deletePatient(patient.id.toString());
                        }),
                    ),
                  )
              )
            ],
          );
        }
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve that by removing the initialization of the future from the `initState` and simply give the future of `patientService.getPatient()` to the `FutureBuilder`, like this:

```
future: patientService.getPatient()
```

And call setState after making sure the patient have been successfully deleted.

The explanation behind doing that is when you delete your patient from the DB, yes it is removed from there, but the UI didn't get an update about the list of patients after the delete. And the reason why calling setState in your case doesn't make a change is because you are assigning the future in `initState` which is called once and only once when the widget is initialized. So when you call setState the future won't be called again hence no new data is fetched.

So what I did is just remove the initialization of the future from `initState` and give it to the `FutureBuilder`, which will be rebuild whenever you call `setState`.

Even though this works, it isn't the ideal solution. Because you are rebuilding your whole widget every time a delete is made which is kinda of heavy considering the FutureBuilder, so what I suggest is checking out some state mangement solutions like Bloc or Mobx or even the Provider package (which isn't a state mangement according to its creator).

Hope that makes clear !

Happy coding !

Answer (score 0):

call setState() inside the onPressed method.

```
onPressed: () {
    patientService.deletePatient(patient.id.toString());
    setState((){});
}),
```

If you are not saving a local copy of the list from which you are deleting an item then this works

Although if the delete method deletes on from wherever you are fetching the items then you will need to call

```
_patients = patientService.getPatient();
```

before calling setState()

Comment: you'll need to add an await before the method call
`_patients = await  patientService.getPatient();`

Answer (score 0):

I think your **deletePatient** is asynchronous method. And you are calling this method without await and after this function setState is called thus widget is getting updated before delete is completed.
If **deletePatient** is asynchronous then add await before calling it and add setState after it.

```
onPressed: () async {
    await patientService.deletePatient(patient.id.toString());
    setState((){});
})
```